# How to use Compose inside Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The documentation describes how to create UI [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) inside Activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        Text("Hello world!")
    }
  }
}
```

But how can I use it inside fragment?

Comment: if am not sure if i got you , use framelayout inside your activity the fragment have there own life cycle and xml file you can use that here is offical documentation link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Answer (score 190, accepted):

`setContent` on `ViewGroup` is now deprecated.

The below is accurate as of Compose **v1.0.0-alpha01**.

For pure compose UI `Fragment`:

```
class ComposeUIFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                Text(text = "Hello world.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For hybrid compose UI `Fragment` - add `ComposeView` to xml layout, then:

```
class ComposeUIFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compose_ui, container, false).apply {
            findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.composeView).setContent {
                Text(text = "Hello world.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `setViewCompositionStrategy(DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)`
in addition the composition strategy should be reviewed when doing this.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#compose-in-fragments

Comment: How to get the NavController in Fragment ?

Answer (score 26):

With `1.0.x` you can :

**- Define a ComposeView in the xml-layout.**

- add a `androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView` in your layout-xml files:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
         ...>
    
        <TextView ../>
    
        <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
            android:id="@+id/compose_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

- Then get the `ComposeView` using the XML ID, set a [Composition strategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/AbstractComposeView#setViewCompositionStrategy(androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewCompositionStrategy)) and call `setContent()`:

```
    class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            _binding = FragmentExampleBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            val view = binding.root
            view.composeView.apply {
                // Dispose the Composition when viewLifecycleOwner is destroyed
                setViewCompositionStrategy(
                    DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner)
                )
                setContent {
                    // In Compose world
                    MaterialTheme {
                        Text("Hello Compose!")
                    }
                }
            }
            return view
        }
    
        /** ... */
    }
```

**- Include a `ComposeView` directly in a fragment.**

```
    class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
                // Dispose the Composition when viewLifecycleOwner is destroyed
                setViewCompositionStrategy(
                    DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner)
                )
    
                setContent {
                    MaterialTheme {
                        // In Compose world
                        Text("Hello Compose!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the `setViewCompositionStrategy` resolve my problem

Comment: You can also use `setViewCompositionStrategy(DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)`

Comment: what about all of the Composable functions?  where do they go?

Comment: Nice answer.   It seems that the second fragment example can also be used with XML by referencing the Fragment in the `tools:context` attribute of the layout element.  No need for binding.

Answer (score 22):

You don't need Fragments with Compose. You can navigate to another screen without needing a Fragment or an Activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(navController, startDestination = "welcome") {
                composable("welcome") { WelcomeScreen(navController) }
                composable("secondScreen") { SecondScreen() }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WelcomeScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Welcome!")
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("secondScreen") }) {
            Text(text = "Continue")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen() {
    Text(text = "Second screen!")
}
```

Comment: While that is true, it does not invalidate the use case of having a fragment serving as the backbone, probably a common scenario for migrating codebases. So that does not answer the question.

Comment: While this is possible it won't be feasible in apps with more than a couple screens.

Comment: @JasonCrosby I don't see why you wouldn't use this in apps with a lot of screens. Yes, the `NavHost` will grow, but you can easily extract this to a separate file so your main activity will stay lean.

Comment: Putting all of your compose code in one activity would end up with an activity thousands of lines long. Maybe even more.

Comment: True. That's why in the real world, you shouldn't actually code like in my example. Each screen (like `WelcomeScreen` and `SecondScreen`) should be in its own file instead of in MainActivity.kt. Same applies for the navigation.

Comment: What about app logic (which you would usually put in ViewModels)?

Comment: App logic should remain in ViewModels: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state

Comment: This might apply if you're using `navigation-compose`, but the question was about Fragments. As Fragments, unlike Navigation-Compose, support screen transitions and type-safe argument passing, etc.

Comment: This seems like a promising approach I was not aware of. How would you do Hilt view model injection with this approach though?

Comment: Quite easily, in your composable screen constructor. like
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    splashViewModel: SplashViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
)

Answer (score 17):

Found it:

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)

    (fragmentView as ViewGroup).setContent {
        Hello("Jetpack Compose")
    }
    return fragmentView
}

@Composable
fun Hello(name: String) = MaterialTheme {
    FlexColumn {
        inflexible {
            // Item height will be equal content height
            TopAppBar( // App Bar with title
                title = { Text("Jetpack Compose Sample") }
            )
        }
        expanded(1F) {
            // occupy whole empty space in the Column
            Center {
                // Center content
                Text("Hello $name!") // Text label
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: can you share the content of fragment_login.xml  ?

Comment: it's deprecated (tested on alpha12)

Answer (score 10):

On my mind if you want to use Jetpack Compose with fragments in a pretty way like this

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
) = contentView {
    Text("Hello world")
}
```

you can create you own extension functions for Fragments

```kotlin
fun Fragment.requireContentView(
    compositionStrategy: ViewCompositionStrategy = DisposeOnDetachedFromWindow,
    context: Context = requireContext(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
): ComposeView {
    val view = ComposeView(context)
    view.setViewCompositionStrategy(compositionStrategy)
    view.setContent(content)
    return view
}

fun Fragment.contentView(
    compositionStrategy: ViewCompositionStrategy = DisposeOnDetachedFromWindow,
    context: Context? = getContext(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
): ComposeView? {
    context ?: return null
    val view = ComposeView(context)
    view.setViewCompositionStrategy(compositionStrategy)
    view.setContent(content)
    return view
}
```

I like this approach because it looks similar to Activity's `setContent { }` extension

Also you can define another CompositionStrategy

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
) = contentView(DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner)) {
    Text("Hello world")
}
```